# WebdriverIO: couldn't find executable for firefox browser using default runner (devtools:puppeteer)

Tags: firefox, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol, wdio

I'm using webdriverIO for some automation testing and have recently migrated from 'selenium-standalone' service to default wdio devtools protocol.

- wdio v.7.16.12
- firefox v.95.0.2

From that point I can't start testing with firefox browser:

```
INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,wdio.conf.js
INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
...
INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Couldn't find executable for browser
...
INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
```

I've tried different combinations of options with 'wdio:devtoolsOptions' and 'moz:firefoxOptions'.

Plus checked whether could help *dumpio: true*, and *'moz:debuggerAddress': true* options.

Also I've tried substitution *browserName* with *product* and adding *binary* and *executablePath* to capabilities.

When passing  *binary: 'path.to.firefox'* to 'moz:firefoxOptions' options, the error message changes to:

```
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Only Nightly release channel is supported in Devtools/Puppeteer for Firefox. Refer to the following issue:
...
```

Any ideas how it could be fixed in webdriverIO (without installing separately puppeteer or puppeteer-firefox)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I took desired for real.

wdio + devtools:puppeteer still work with Firefox Nightly only – https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/7916